# Howto use a fold expression with a specific type?

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

I've a function to check if a `std::string` contains a substring. I pass the strings around as `std::string_view`, such that no copy takes place.

```
bool containsSubstr(std::string_view str, std::string_view substr)
{
    return str.find(substr) != std::string::npos;
}
```

I now want to make a function, using the new C++17 fold expressions, to check if a string contains several substrings. Again, I want to pass them by `std::string_view`s.

How can I do that?

```
template<typename... Substrs>
bool containsAllSubstr(std::string_view str, Substrs... substrs)
{
    return  (containsSubstr(str, substrs) && ...);
}
```

As far as I know, the above version will take the substring's as the type with which they came in. So a `std::string` would be copied. How can I fix the type to `std::string_view`? Something like:

```
template<> // does not compile
bool containsAllSubstr(std::string_view str, std::string_view... substrs)
{
    return  (containsSubstr(str, substrs) && ...);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have a function parameter pack of a specific type. But this is fine (once you add `const&`):

```
template <typename... Substrs>
bool containsAllSubstr(std::string_view str, Substrs const&... substrs)
{
    return  (containsSubstr(str, substrs) && ...);
}
```

That won't make any copies, and just won't compile if you pass in something not convertible to `string_view`. If you want to make it SFINAE-friendly, could just add a condition:

```
template <typename... Substrs,
    std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<Substrs const&, std::string_view> && ...), int> = 0>
bool containsAllSubstr(std::string_view str, Substrs const&... substrs)
{
    return  (containsSubstr(str, substrs) && ...);
}
```

---

Or, if you're open to a slight change in syntax, you could take an array:

```
template <size_t N>
bool containsAllSubstr(std::string_view str, std::string_view (&substrs)[N]);
```

but then you don't actually have a pack immediately. But then, you could just write a loop. Or if you don't need compile-time size at all:

```
bool containsAllSubstr(std::string_view str, std::initializer_list<std::string_view> substrs);
```

Comment: `std::initializer_list< std::string_view >`?

Comment: @Yakk Or that, if you don't actually need the compile-time size (which... you probably don't?)

Comment: In my code base, I'd actually use a `my_ns::span< std::string_view >`, and my `span` has a `std::initializer_list< remove_const<T> >` ctor.  It works well, and it means I can pass in arrays, `{}` enclosed list (including empty), vectors, or whatever.

Comment: @Yakk Does that... work? Wouldn't the `initializer_list` get destroyed and leave you with dangling pointers?

Comment: It lasts until the end of the full expression the initializer list is created in.  Which is longer than the function call.  Might need a `const&` in there to ensure it works.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, I think the `const&` is necessary.